# Xpath query pulled from MySQL not working

Tags: php, mysql, xpath

I am trying to make a long list of xpath query tests into a much more condensed function and having issues getting the xpath queries to work once pulled from mysql.

This is driving me batty, can anyone explain where I am going wrong please?

Example MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `spidey_regex` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `regexp` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT INTO `spidey_regex` (`id`, `regexp`) VALUES (1, '''//div[starts-with(@id, "stuff")]''');
```

Example PHP code using xpath:

```
<?php
   $html = '<div id="stuff123"><a href="link1.html">Link 1</a><a href="#link">Link 2</a><a href="link2.html">Link 3</a></div>';
   $cnt=0;
       $dom = new DOMDocument();
       @$dom->loadHTML($html);
       $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
       $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 
     $myresult = mysql_query("select * from spidey_regex",$db);
   while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($myresult)){
     $regexp = stripslashes(trim($myrow[regexp]));
     $result = $xpath->query($regexp);  // use xpath with query from MySQL
     foreach($result as $e){ $cnt++; }
       if($cnt == '0'){ 
         continue; 
       } 
       else { 
         echo "1. Got here!!"; 
       }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Yikes, what's that `stripslashes` doing in there?  Please tell me you don't have `magic_quotes` on.  Have you checked to ensure that the string coming out of the database is actually correct?

Comment: Checked that yes, the proper string is coming out of mysql. The stripslashes was not really necessary in the first place either, thanks.

Comment: So DOMXPath::query returns a DOMNodeList -- what's the value of `$result->length`?  Is it always zero?  What happens when you manually trigger the same XPath queries?  Can you post some sample XML that your query should match?

Comment: Charles: manually doing them works fine, I am just trying to get away from 15 stacked tests per checked page. The sample xml is located in my post as $html

Comment: What do the three single quotes around the regexp stored in the table mean?

Comment: tandu: that is just how mysql exported that table. I assume it puts 2 extra single quotes to escape the single quote in my query which would normally be: '//div[starts-with(@id, "stuff")]'

Comment: Hm, missed that.  Yes, this is very, very odd.  There is no reason your code should not work.

Comment: Ah, that's it then!  Answering...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `spidey_regex` (`id`, `regexp`) VALUES (1, '''//div[starts-with(@id, "stuff")]''');
```

The double-quote-to-escape thing is a bit weird.  If we were to use the normal backslashes, instead we'd see:

```
'\'//div[starts-with(@id, "stuff")]\''
```

In other words, your XPath query has one too many layers of quotes, and is being rejected by the XPath parser.  Once you remove the quotes from the value in the database, your query should work.

---

Proof at the PHP Interactive prompt:

```
php > $html = '<div id="stuff123"><a href="link1.html">Link 1</a><a href="#link">Link 2</a><a href="link2.html">Link 3</a></div>';
php > $dom = new DOMDocument();
php > $dom->loadHTML($html);
php > $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
php > $regexp = '//div[starts-with(@id, "stuff")]';
php > $result = $xpath->query($regexp);
php > echo $result->length;
1
php > $regexp = "'{$regexp}'";
php > $result = $xpath->query($regexp);
php > echo $result->length;
0
```

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly across the board, thanks. I hate it when it is something so stupidly simple  :(

Comment: are you open to new projects? I have need of a coder with xpath knowledge on a project I have going quickly.

Comment: @Jaime, I actually know very little about xpath, but thanks for the consideration.